# Store geometry change on modify interaction OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geometry, features

I am using OpenLayers modify interaction with events `modifystart` and `modifyend`. I am trying to remember state of feature before it is modified.
I do it this way:

```
var modificirane_cestice=new Object()

modify.on('modifystart',function(e){
    e.features.forEach(function(feature){
        if(modificirane_cestice[ogc_fid]){
            return }
        else{
            modificirane_cestice[ogc_fid]=new Array()
            modificirane_cestice[ogc_fid].push(new ol.Feature({geometry:feature.getGeometry()}))
            }

    })
    })

 modify.on('modifyend',function(e){
    e.features.forEach(function(feature){
    izmjenjena_geometrija=feature.getGeometry()

    modificirane_cestice[ogc_fid].push(new ol.Feature({geometry:izmjenjena_geometrija}))
    posljednja_geometrija=modificirane_cestice[ogc_fid].length-1
    pg_pov=ol.sphere.getArea(modificirane_cestice[ogc_fid][0].getGeometry())
    zadnja_pov=ol.sphere.getArea(modificirane_cestice[ogc_fid][posljednja_geometrija].getGeometry())
    console.log(pg_pov+".... zadnja pov...."+zadnja_pov)
    postotak=pg_pov/zadnja_pov
    console.log(postotak)
    if(postotak<0.9){
        console.log("postotak prelazi 10% i iznosi: "+(1-postotak)*100+"%")
    }
    })
    })
```

I expected to get two different areas and features but in the end I got the same one. I know there is problem in referencing feature object but don't know how to solve it. I want to create a new object which are independent on their source object.

Comment: I think you will need to use `geometry:feature.getGeometry().clone()` otherwise the features will share the same geometry object and a change to one will change both

Comment: @Mike Thanks, it works now :)

Comment: @Mike Please, put your comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `geometry:feature.getGeometry().clone()` otherwise the features will share the same geometry object and a change to one will change both.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i got the opposite case, i've loaded features from a geojson object from a url, whenever i use modify interaction over it it just creates new vertices while preserving the existing ones, any help on this?
thanks

Comment: @Mohab Khaled  Do you only want to move existing vertices?  Then you should set `insertVertexCondition: never` to prevent new ones being added (or use a modifier key to made it harder to accidentally add new vertices).

Comment: never is string?

Comment: used ol.events.condition.never but still getting new vertices, how can i upload this so you can see what i mean, currently i have a gif showing the case

Comment: also used false with the same result

Comment: i've posted this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445815/openlayers-adding-modify-interaction-while-preventing-new-vertices-on-geojson-fe